# Spring Data JPA native query result binding

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="hourMapping",
    classes=@ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=Representation.class,
            columns={
                    @ColumnResult(name="hour", type=BigDecimal.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name="transactions", type=BigDecimal.class)
            }
            )
    )

@NamedNativeQuery(name="MyEntity.reportByHour", query="SELECT hour,SUM(tran_per_hour) AS transactions FROM MY_ENTITY GROUP BY hour ORDER BY hour"
    ,resultSetMapping="hourMapping")

@Table(name="MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
```

**Pojo class:**

```
@Data //Lombok
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
public class Representation {

public Representation(BigDecimal hour, BigDecimal transactions) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.transactions = transactions;
}

private BigDecimal hour;
private BigDecimal transactions;
```

Repository interface:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityPK> {
    List<Representation> reportByHour();
}
```

When I run the endpoint which invokes the native query, I get exception:

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.representation.Representation] for value '{0, 198}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [com.representation.Representation]

Now if I just have "hour" field returned from my native query (and relevant changes to POJO constructor etc) it works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, false alarm. My hibernate dependencies were all messed up and causing conflicts so resulting in the above exception.

After fixing these dependency issues, works great!!

Long story short: let spring-boot-* handle most hibernate dependencies instead of overriding or managing your own.